# Wordpress Post/Page Editor not Working - Cannot Read Property Error

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

We have a few sites using `Wordpress 4.9.6`. When trying to edit/add a post or page I see this:

[image: WordPress Post Editor - Blank]

And then upon inspecting the console, everything seems normal. However, when I click on the `text` button to try the text editor, this error appears in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined
    at q (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,sug&load[]=gest,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,wp-a11y,jquery&load[]=-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,underscore,word-count,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,&load[]=media-models,wp-plupload,wp-mediaelement,wp-api-request,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgareaselect,image-e&load[]=dit,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,editor,wplink,media-upload,wp-embed&ver=4.9.6:716)
    at e (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,sug&load[]=gest,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,wp-a11y,jquery&load[]=-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,underscore,word-count,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,&load[]=media-models,wp-plupload,wp-mediaelement,wp-api-request,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgareaselect,image-e&load[]=dit,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,editor,wplink,media-upload,wp-embed&ver=4.9.6:716)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,sug&load[]=gest,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,wp-a11y,jquery&load[]=-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,underscore,word-count,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,&load[]=media-models,wp-plupload,wp-mediaelement,wp-api-request,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgareaselect,image-e&load[]=dit,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,editor,wplink,media-upload,wp-embed&ver=4.9.6:716)
    at C (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
    at HTMLDocument.d (tinymce.min.js?ver=4711-20180425:2)
```

This site has NO plugins, and I have tried the only suggested solution I can find, of adding:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

to our wp-config.php file.

There is a script not loading on the post edit pages if you look on the network tab:

```
http://search.rocketfacts.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js?wp-mce-4711-20180425
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a permanent solution to this, however for those also struggling I found a simple word-around.

1. Login to wordpress admin.
2. Hover over the 'users' option, and select 'your profile'
3. Check the box labeled 'Disable the visual editor when writing' and save your settings.

When receiving an error loading TinyMCE (cannot load property, mixed content message), this only inhibits your work while on the visual editor tab. Well, since the visual editor is the default on most posts and pages this makes it impossible to edit your wordpress pages and posts. By disabling the visual editor you no longer have to worry about TinyMCE not loading correctly. This hopefully will help out others while we wait to find more information about this error.

Answer (score 0):

This should mostly be a plugin error or the theme itself... Double check and disable any and every plugin available first and try again.

if problem persists, then continue below.

Go to the network or console tab on your browser and check the list of all the .js file loaded on the wordpress site.. you can start the trace from there.

Let me know what you get so i can help futher

Comment: As I said in my post here are zero plugins on this site. The script that is not loading is http://search.rocketfacts.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js?wp-mce-4711-20180425

Comment: There are two ways to solve this, You can manually search for the line in your text editor where the code is not been well imported due to bad links and fix it with the actual path to the scripts or

use wp_enqueue_script to load the scripts in wordpress function file.

Both ways should solve the problem

Comment: When loading the URL to the script provided the script is loaded. So shouldn't it be working?